# Regex with one open and close bracket within an number

Tags: regex, brackets

since few days I am sitting and fighting with the regular expression without any success

My first expression, what I want:

- brackets just one time, doesn't matter where
- Text or numbers before and after brackets optional
- numbers within the brackets

Example what is allowed:

- [32] text1
- text1 [5]
- text1 [103] text2
- text1
- [123]
- [some value [33]] (maybe to complicated, would be not so important?)

My second expression is similar but just numbers before and after the brackets instead text

- [32] 11
- 11 [5]
- 11 [103] 22
- 11
- [123]

no match:

- [12] xxx [5] (brackets are more than one time)
- [aa] xxx (no number within brackets)

That's what I did but is not working because I don't know how to do with the on-time-brackets:

```
^.*\{?[0-9]*\}.*$
```

From some other answer I found also that, that's looks good but I need that for the numbers:

```
^[^\{\}]*\{[^\{\}]*\}[^\{\}]*$
```

I want to use later the number in the brackets and replace with some other values, just for some additional information, if important.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain `[some value [33]]`

Comment: Is this your answer? ``^[^\]]*\[(\d+?)\][^[]*$`` If it is? Tell me to i explain it. Check it: https://regexr.com/6fhdq (You have to take just group#1) (Ignore the \n , that is for avoiding taking two lines). Also please mention your regex engine, Programming langauge.

Comment: @MMMahdy-PAPION, in the third to the forth line, the matches are sticking together.

Comment: @Henryc17 Thanks, just added a temporary `\n` in the group. I still not sure he need to match all of phrase without any bracket or not.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen the user can write what ever they want (every kind of brackets), important for me is just the [33]. But I think that case is maybe too complicated or looks like too complicated. Just nice to have. But I think the answer of Henryc17 catches all my cases. Just the 2nd expression with the numbers would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
^([^\]\n]*\[\d+\])?[^[\n]*$
```

[Live example](https://regexr.com/6fk5l)

**Update:** For just numbers:

```
^[\d ]*(\[\d+\])?[\d ]*$
```

##### Explaination:

- `^` Start of line
- `[^...]` Negative character set --> `[^\]]` Any character except `]`

  - `*` Zero or more length of the Class/Character set
- `\d` 0-9

  - `+` One or more length of the Class/Character set
- `(...)?` 0 or 1 of the group
- `$` End of line

**Note:** These RegExs can return empty matches.

Thanks to @MMMahdy-PAPION! He improved the answer.

Comment: Looks good, Thanks! What I have to do if I want instead a string/text just numbers like in my 2nd case?